# Select multiple (non-aggregate function) columns with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select the max value from one column, while grouping by another non-unique id column which has multiple duplicate values. The original database looks something like:

```
mukey    | comppct_r | name | type
65789    | 20        | a    | 7n
65789    | 15        | b    | 8m
65789    | 1         | c    | 1o
65790    | 10        | a    | 7n
65790    | 26        | b    | 8m
65790    | 5         | c    | 1o
...
```

This works just fine using:

```
SELECT c.mukey, Max(c.comppct_r) AS ComponentPercent
FROM c
GROUP BY c.mukey;
```

Which returns a table like:

```
mukey    | ComponentPercent
65789    | 20
65790    | 26
65791    | 50
65792    | 90
```

I want to be able to add other columns in without affecting the GROUP BY function, to include columns like name and type into the output table like:

```
mukey    | comppct_r | name | type
65789    | 20        | a    | 7n
65790    | 26        | b    | 8m
65791    | 50        | c    | 7n
65792    | 90        | d    | 7n
```

but it always outputs an error saying I need to use an aggregate function with select statement. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Added that to the op, Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have yourself a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. This is one of the possible solutions:

```
select c.mukey, c.comppct_r, c.name, c.type
from c yt
inner join(
    select c.mukey, max(c.comppct_r) comppct_r
    from c
    group by c.mukey
) ss on c.mukey = ss.mukey and c.comppct_r= ss.comppct_r
```

Another possible approach, same output:

```
select c1.*
from c c1
left outer join c c2
on (c1.mukey = c2.mukey and c1.comppct_r < c2.comppct_r)
where c2.mukey is null;
```

There's a comprehensive and explanatory answer on the topic here: [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: What does the 'ss' in "ss on c.mukey = ss.mukey and c.comppct_r= ss.comppct_r" mean?

Comment: `ss` is the name I gave to the derived table (the structure declared between parenthesis)

Comment: how second solution works? in my case it does nothing - just displays all rows. It seems that that approach must use group by as well...

Comment: How fast is the first query, if there are a lot of rows in a table? e.g. One million, and if limit is applied e.g. limit 50

Answer (score 1):

Any non-aggregate column should be there in Group By clause .. why??

```
                  t1
x1           y1           z1
1            2             5
2            2             7
```

Now you are trying to write a query  like:

```
select x1,y1,max(z1) from t1 group by y1;
```

Now this query will result only one row, but what should be the value of x1?? This is basically an undefined behaviour. To overcome this, SQL will error out this query.

Now, coming to the point, you can either chose aggregate function for x1 or you can add x1 to group by. Note that this all depends on your requirement.

If you want all rows with aggregation on z1 grouping by y1, you may use SubQ approach.

```
Select x1,y1,(select max(z1) from t1  where tt.y1=y1 group by y1)
 from t1 tt;
```

This will produce a result like:

```
                  t1
x1           y1           max(z1)
1            2             7
2            2             7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a virtual table as follows:

```
SELECT vt.*,c.name FROM(
SELECT c.mukey, Max(c.comppct_r) AS ComponentPercent
FROM c
GROUP BY c.muke;
) as VT, c 
WHERE VT.mukey = c.mukey
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add additional columns without adding them to the `GROUP BY` or applying an aggregate function. The reason for that is, that the values of a column can be different inside one group. For example, you could have two rows:

```
mukey    | comppct_r | name | type
65789    | 20        | a    | 7n
65789    | 20        | b    | 9f
```

How should the aggregated group look like for the columns `name` and `type`?

If name and type is always the same inside a group, just add it to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT c.mukey, Max(c.comppct_r) AS ComponentPercent
FROM c
GROUP BY c.muke, c.name, c.type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'Having' clause

```
SELECT *
FROM c
GROUP BY c.mukey
HAVING c.comppct_r = Max(c.comppct_r);
```