# Remove Unique Values in Access Sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to remove certain rows based on unique values within the table and still display the other column data associated with the row.

For example:

```
x------------------------------------------------ x
x Process ID  Name         Address    Random Data x
x------------------------------------------------ x
x 123        TestName     TestAdd    qwrj3ri      x
x 456        TestName2    TestAdd    qwerty       x
x 789        TestName     TestAdd    qwrj3ri      x
x 1234       Testing123   tester     asdfghjk     x
---------------------------------------------------
```

In access, after importing the table from excel.

I used this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Test.Name, Test.Address
FROM Test;
```

The problem is that while it displays the Unique `Name` and `Address`, I also would like to display the `Process ID`, and `Random Data` column that is associated with the Unique Name, and Address. What I am trying to do is remove duplicate based on the name and address and still display the relevant data for the unique value/row.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a sample output?

Comment: why do you have mysql tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select multiple (non-aggregate function) columns with GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411177/select-multiple-non-aggregate-function-columns-with-group-by)

Comment: well I am trying to keep the ID as it will be used to search an existing system for the given entitiy. There are two rows with the same name and address. I want to remove one of them and keep the other. The duplicates are decided by the name and address. When I use the distinct query it returns the unique rows withouth the ID being displayed and the other columns

Comment: @user3341712 Okay! How do you determine which `Process ID` and `Random Data` to pull? It will return multiple records if we join back on `Name` or `Address`.

Comment: @FutbolFan For me all sql - mysql :)

Comment: @splash58 Same goes for me all sql = SQL Server. :)

Comment: @FutbolFan I want it to pull the first process ID associated with the name. I just included Random Data to represent the other columns that I currently have. Basically if I have two process IDs 123 and 789. I want it to pull 789 for TestName. Any idea how can pull the data for the other columns associated with the entity. So , taking a look at the table I included above. I want it to display the first instance of the having the same name and address which in this case is TestName with the Process ID 123.

Comment: @Bulat  The method you sugested deals with the arranging max, min values.

Comment: @user3341712 without more details on the desired output that method seems to do what you need.

Comment: @Bulat http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaf9b/1 . Here is the output I get after running the distinct query. However, I am trying to also display the ID, and other columns with that are associated with the unique entity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't agree that [Select multiple (non-aggregate function) columns with GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411177/select-multiple-non-aggregate-function-columns-with-group-by) provides the answer:

```
SELECT t.ProcessID, t.Name, t.Address, RandomData
FROM Test t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT c.Name,c.Address, MIN(c.ProcessID) ProcessID
FROM test c
GROUP by c.Name, c.Address
) ss ON t.Name = ss.Name AND t.Address= ss.Address
AND t.ProcessID = ss.ProcessID
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaf9b/6

Comment: I am a bit confused..Why did you select distinct process id and random data?  I am trying to find duplicates by two criteria which is the name and address. From running your code, it seems to provide me the values that I am looking for. But, trying to understand the syntax of the code.

Comment: what is the puspose of using T within your insert statement? Access keeps displaying a missing semicolon at the end of the statement error and there seems to be nothing wrong with the code you provided. When I ran it in sqlfiddle, it seems fine. But, Access acts differently

Comment: You don't need distinct indeed

Comment: I am not sure why it does not work in MS Access. sqlfiddle is working in MySQL which can be different. Actually there is no T in my sqlfiddle